# Laravel 5 Seeder - multiple rows in DB

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, row, laravel-5.1

I was wondering if it's possible to insert multiple rows like this (or something like this):

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class SettingTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        DB::table('settings')->insert(
            [
                'key' => 'username',
                'value' => 'testusername'
            ],
            [
                'key' => 'password',
                'value' => 'plain'
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

I have a **table settings** in my database with columns **key & value**.

The problem with the code above is that he only inserts the first one ... .

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need to wrap your arrays in another array, so it would look like this:

```
DB::table('settings')->insert([
    [
        'key' => 'username',
        'value' => 'testusername'
    ],
    [
        'key' => 'password',
        'value' => 'plain'
    ]
]);
```

Notice the wrapping array.

What you are doing now is actually sending two separate arrays to the `insert()` method.

Comment: I tried this but getting "Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'field list'"

Answer (score 1):

you can use insert method from eloquent for bulk save like

```
Settings::insert([[
            'key' => 'username',
            'value' => 'testusername'
        ],
        [
            'key' => 'password',
            'value' => 'plain'
        ]]);
```

Comment: This will fail, as you're actually sending `insert(array(...), array(...))`. The insert expects an array of arrays.

Answer (score -1):

Just repeate the DB::table code as much as you want inside the run method!:

```
DB::table('settings')->insert(
            [
                'key' => 'username',
                'value' => 'testusername1'
            ]
        );

 DB::table('settings')->insert(
            [
                'key' => 'username',
                'value' => 'testusername2'
            ]
        );

 DB::table('settings')->insert(
            [
                'key' => 'username',
                'value' => 'testusername3'
            ]
        );
```